# How to Assign button outside bottom of text area?

Tags: css, button, textarea, bootstrap-4

Hi Image of currently having row[image: Attached image is currently having one]

But I want the result as dispalyed below [image: displayed here]

I used 5 rows in text area so I want the button to be displayed near the bottom end of text area.

coding as below:

```
<div class="row">
<p class="col-sm-6 col-md-10 ">
<b >Mail</b> <br />                                                         
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Email"></textarea>
</p>
<p class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
<br />
<a id="btnSave"  onclick="SaveValue()" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-xs-block"><span style="color: #fff;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</a></p> </div>
```

I found few answers suggesting to add bootstrap 4.0 link. but this one actually not working,but changed my display only. Image as follows [image]

Comment: does my answer work for you ?

Comment: There is no need for extra code, as you are using bootstrap 4 you can achieve it just using the new bootstrap native classes... Please see my answer...

Comment: use inline form of bootstrap. I have provided an example. Just check that and customize according to you. Might be that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all your suggestions. I tried above all. I am not sure whether I tried your answers wrongly, or something else, I never got my expected result without any flaws. After that just added `<br />`  into the code fixed my issue. So that, I just added my answer below.

```
<p class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 ">
<b >Mail </b> <br />
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Email"></textarea>
</p>
<p class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-xs-12" ">
<br /><br /><br  /><br /><br />
<a id="btnSave"  onclick="SaveValue()" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-xs-block"><span style="color: #fff;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</a>
</p>
```

This fixed my issue and got my expected result

Answer (score 3):

The most dirty answer for this question is below, but it works for me

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="position:relative">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-10 ">
<b >Mail</b> <br />                                                         
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Email"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2" style="position:relative">
<br />
<a id="btnSave"  onclick="SaveValue()" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-xs-block" style="position:absolute;bottom:0"><span style="color: #fff;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</a></div> </div>
```

Comment: hi, no its not working for me.. after I add that bootsrap link it changed my whole page display only..like change font size button size and colors only.. but my expected result is  not available

Comment: @Halim, will you please share screenshot ?

Comment: @Halim, which css library you are using ?,  i was thinking  you are using bootstrap. that's why i imported bootstrap.

Comment: i used  <link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> but 
I think ur one version 4.0 right? both quite different right?

Comment: @Halim, you can use your own version of bootstrap, it is not necessary to use bootstrap version that i am using.

Comment: I dont know how to add screenshot/image in comment,bcoz I found no option to add.. When I use your code it only changes my displays, after I add the link ref of bootstrap 4.0.. I may add the new image in my question

Comment: Suddenly I tie up in some urgent work, sory for late rly. If I use ur code without the link its not working, if I use the link it change my page display.

Answer (score 2):

Use the inline form of bootstrap. Also make position of button to position absolute and bottom:0 and parent div to position:relative. SO that it will be in bottom area in respect to its parent.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<div class="container" style="position:relative">
  <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-10">
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" style="position:absolute;bottom:15px;" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: When I try to add links for bootsrap, my page completely changed. Im not too good in bootstrap, though I think Our project already used some previous versions of bootstrap. Suddenly I tie up in some urgent work, sory for late rly.

Comment: @Halim which version you are using. add cdn links in your question so that we can answer properly

Comment: the link we used under shared folder is <link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: open that file and check version  @Halim

Answer (score 1):

you better use table

```
<div class="row">
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                <b >Mail</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Email"></textarea>
     </td>
     <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
            <a id="btnSave"  onclick="SaveValue()" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-xs-block"><span style="color: #fff;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</a>
     </td>
 </tr>       
</table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Its working but not exactly like what I want . It create new row for the table below my expected <div row>

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention you,that in row there is 3 field with col-4 as Time, col-6 as EMail and col-2 as save button. If I try to add this code with or without the table,still it comes one row below

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `Bootstrap 4`, you can use `d-flex align-items-end` to your button wrapper from the new [Bootstrap 4 flexbox utilities...](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#align-items)

Also, change you paragraphs columns to div's as it not a paragraph, see: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-10 ">
      <b >Mail</b> <br />                                                         
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Email"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 d-flex align-items-end">
      <a id="btnSave"  onclick="SaveValue()" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-xs-block">
        <span style="color: #fff;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
        Save
      </a>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

> Without using Bootstrap you can add class to your wrapper and add the following to your css

```
.form-wrapper > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```css
.form-wrapper > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row form-wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-10 ">
      <b >Mail</b> <br />                                                         
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Email"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
      <a id="btnSave"  onclick="SaveValue()" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-xs-block">
        <span style="color: #fff;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
        Save
      </a>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I updated my question kindly check  it out. When I import the link for bootstrap 4.0 it changed my page look and display

Comment: I tried your one. It works only only when I include the href link, but it completely changed my page display each and every tab,button and table size and also, it cannot load data.

Comment: Alright, I could see in you've tagged the `bootstrap-4`, anyway I updated the answer.